# How to get max value at 0th index of the tuple from a list where each element of the list is a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get max value at 0th index of the tuple from a list where each element of the list is a tuple. e.g.

`li = [(100, "Apple"), (50, "Banana"), (150, "Mango")]`

Is it possible to get `maximum value at 0th index of the tuple` without sorting the list?

Comment: To find the max value you need to go through the whole list once - no need to sort. You can do this manually (`for el in li:` and then remember the max one manually) or simpy type `max(li)` - for tuples max checks the first element of the tuple, further tuple elements only come into play if the earlier ones are tied.

Comment: Just curious - why did you not simply experiment with max and loops yourself?

Comment: Sure @PatrickArtner just wanted to know best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max(li)` will simply return the element with the highest value by comparing the first element of each tuple, then the second in case of equality.

```
>>> max(li)
(150, 'Mango')
```

If you want to get the maximum value using another element of the tuple, you can use the `key` parameter of the function `max` to select the value to compare.

Answer (score 0):

`max` allows you to specify `key` which takes a lambda expression that indicates how to value each element upon comparison. You can do as follow

```
li = [(100, "Apple"), (50, "Banana"), (150, "Mango")]
result = max(li, key=lambda tup: tup[0])    # (150, "Mango")
max_value = result[0]                       # 150
```

Comment: IIRC `max` will use the first tuple element anyway, the second only counts if the first ties - so no need to specify anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a generator expression inside max:

```
print(max(x for (x,y) in li))
# 150
```

or, more generally with indexing:

```
print(max(t[0] for t in li))
# 150
```

The generator expression will yield the first element of each tuple to max, and max will keep track and return the maximum of these values -- what you want.